# Plotting Stacked bar plot of large dataset and setting bar limits of plot in r

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a stacked bar plot of my dataset which is data.csv and which is as below.Apologies for posting large dataset.

```
degree  Freq.x  Freq.y
1   2978 0
2   1779 33
3   1390 22
4   919 19
5   787 16
6   676 22
7   578 16
8   513 23
9   460 11
10  376 17
11  345 13
12  292 17
13  291 14
14  286 8
15  269 15
16  216 10
17  192 18
18  183 10
19  184 7
20  190 10
21  157 9
22  155 14
23  127 9
24  151 15
25  119 10
26  102 6
27  113 7
28  99  6
29  98  4
30  103 7
31  94  11
32  79  7
33  76  5
34  73  8
35  76  11
36  59  5
37  58  5
38  61  5
39  63  7
40  68  9
41  63  4
42  57  8
43  45  6
44  45  4
45  39  3
46  40  6
47  42  6
48  30  3
49  36  7
50  28  5
51  33  1
52  32  6
53  34  5
54  43  4
55  35  6
56  29  2
57  27  4
58  35  6
59  25  4
60  24  4
61  32  4
62  15  2
63  24  5
64  25  4
65  23  9
66  25  7
67  27  7
68  22  7
69  23  7
70  17  6
71  19  4
72  19  4
73  19  2
74  18  2
75  19  6
76  12  3
77  25  6
78  23  9
79  20  4
80  17  6
81  15  5
82  13  4
83  14  4
84  13  5
85  15  1
86  13  1
87  12  5
88  14  5
89  16  4
90  12  3
91  10  3
92  12  5
93  12  7
94  10  0
95  11  4
96  12  3
97  6   5
98  20  7
99  5   3
100 8   3
101 11  2
102 11  3
103 8   0
104 14  4
105 15  2
106 7   0
107 7   1
108 6   0
109 9   2
110 10  1
111 8   1
112 6   1
113 8   1
114 8   2
115 7   4
116 3   1
117 4   2
118 5   0
120 5   0
121 1   0
122 9   2
123 7   3
124 4   1
125 3   0
126 3   2
127 7   3
128 5   3
129 3   1
130 3   0
131 5   1
132 5   2
133 2   0
134 5   2
135 10  1
136 5   2
137 3   1
138 7   2
139 6   2
140 3   1
141 5   1
142 9   4
143 3   1
144 2   1
145 4   2
146 2   0
147 2   2
148 3   1
149 1   0
150 1   0
151 2   1
152 3   1
153 3   1
154 2   1
155 3   1
156 6   4
157 4   2
158 3   1
159 4   1
160 2   1
161 2   1
163 3   1
164 5   2
165 2   1
166 3   0
167 4   4
168 2   1
169 1   0
170 2   2
171 3   2
172 1   0
173 4   3
174 3   2
175 1   1
177 3   3
178 3   2
179 1   0
180 3   1
181 2   0
182 1   1
183 3   1
184 2   2
185 2   1
186 3   1
187 2   1
188 1   1
191 1   0
192 1   0
193 1   0
195 4   2
196 2   2
197 4   1
198 1   0
199 2   1
200 1   0
201 2   2
202 1   0
204 2   0
206 3   1
207 1   0
208 1   0
209 2   1
211 1   1
212 2   1
213 2   2
214 1   1
215 1   1
218 2   2
220 2   1
222 3   1
223 2   2
224 1   1
225 1   1
226 1   1
227 2   1
228 2   1
230 3   1
231 1   1
233 2   2
234 3   1
235 1   1
236 1   1
237 1   1
239 2   2
241 1   1
242 1   0
243 1   0
244 1   1
245 1   1
246 1   1
247 2   0
250 2   1
251 3   2
252 1   1
253 2   2
254 1   1
256 1   1
258 2   1
260 1   1
262 1   1
264 1   0
267 1   1
268 1   1
269 1   1
270 1   1
271 2   1
272 1   1
275 2   1
276 1   1
277 2   2
278 1   0
280 1   1
283 1   0
285 2   1
290 1   1
291 1   1
294 1   1
299 1   1
301 4   3
303 1   1
304 2   0
305 1   1
307 1   1
311 1   1
314 2   1
317 1   1
318 1   1
319 1   1
321 1   1
323 1   1
329 2   1
330 1   1
333 1   0
334 1   1
335 1   1
337 1   1
339 1   1
342 1   1
343 1   0
350 2   2
356 1   1
368 1   0
370 2   2
377 1   1
390 1   1
392 1   1
394 1   1
406 1   1
408 1   1
409 1   1
419 1   1
424 1   1
427 1   1
451 1   1
459 1   1
461 1   1
462 1   0
478 1   1
479 1   0
488 1   1
530 1   1
550 1   1
553 1   1
568 1   0
594 1   1
608 1   1
622 1   1
625 1   1
626 1   1
628 1   1
646 1   1
648 1   1
652 1   1
655 1   1
656 1   1
660 1   0
688 1   1
723 1   1
732 1   1
740 1   1
761 1   1
769 1   0
845 1   1
865 1   1
1063 1  1
1105 1  1
1242 1  1
1737 1  1
1989 1  1
2456 1  1
9588 1  1
```

I want to plot stacked barplot in which  i want to compare the degree in freq.x and freq.y field. That means on x axis there will be degree and on on y axis there will be frequency.I tried the ggplot2 function in r and plotted stacked bar plot. But the problem is my dataset is large so i want to combine bar limits. The code which i tried is as follow.

```
d_ap <- read.csv("data.csv")
l_nw <- data.frame(d_ap)
library(reshape2)
final_df <- melt(l_nw, id.var="Degree")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(final_df, aes(x = Degree, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

this will output a barplot but i want to set bar limits on x-axis and in my desired output of bar plot on x-axis i want to plot degree from 1 to 10 in individual bars. Then from degree 11 to 9588 i want to club it in bars like 11 to 20 then 20 to 30 and then 30 to 50 and 50 to 9588. How can i set bar limits on x-axis like this..?? So that by setting this bar limit i can better visualize my stacked bar plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
final_df$cdegree=cut(final_df$degree,c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,30,50,9590))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(final_df, aes(x = cdegree, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]